# (0,1) with subspace topology is not compact

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Proposition:
>   $\left ( 0,1 \right )$ with subspace topology is not compact.

The collection $c=\left \{ \frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\right \}$ is an open covering of $\left ( 0,1 \right )$.

Let $\bar{c}$ be a finite subcollection of c where for the open sets in $\bar{c}$ there exists a largest $\bar{n} \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ where it terminates.
Indeed, we have a nested sequence of sets.

It suffice to show that $\left ( 0,1 \right ) \subseteq  \cup _{\alpha \in J}\left ( \frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n} \right )_{\alpha}$.

Can someone assist me in concluding the proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you missing parentheses in the definition of $c$? It should be $c = \{(\ldots)\ : \ldots\}$.

Comment: I am. I will have it edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any finite collection $\bar{c}$ will have a largest $\bar{n}$, in which case any $x \in \left(0, \frac{1}{\bar{n}}\right)\subset (0,1)$ is not in the union of $\bar{c}$.

To show that $c$ covers $(0,1)$, let $x \in (0,1)$. Then since $x > 0$, there exists $n \in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < x$, in which case $x \in \left(\frac{1}{n}, 1- \frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Thus $(0,1)$ is covered by $c$, but not finitely.

Comment: Would you mind expounding on the first statement?
The sets in $\bar{c}$ are (0,1),(1/2,1/2),(1/3,2/3)....which terminates at some really small open interval fora given finite large n.

Comment: @Mathematicing Pick $x = \frac{1}{2\bar{n}}$ for example. Then $x \in (0,1)$ but not in the finite collection.

Comment: you're right. I was being an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

Elements in $C$ are in $\left\{\left(\frac{1}{n}, 1- \frac {1}{n}\right): n \in \mathcal{A}=\mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus\{1\}\right\}$. The actual covering looks like;

$$(0,1) \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathcal{A}}\left(\frac{1}{n}, 1- \frac {1}{n}\right)$$

i.e a finite sub-collection $\bar{C}$ has the property that;

$$(0,1) \subset \bigcup_{j}\left(\frac{1}{j}, 1- \frac {1}{j}\right)$$

The above union is take over $j$ in some finite subset of $\mathcal{A}$. Now just let $k$ be the smallest such element in this finite subset. Then we take $x \in (0,1)$ with $x> 1- \frac{1}{k}$. You choose $k$ this way since any bigger values pushes you more to the left of the endpt $1$ i.e if $j>k$ then;

$$1 - \frac{1}{j} < 1- \frac{1}{k}$$